# Is there any expression for the Feigenbaum constants ?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, chaos

It has puzzled me for a long time that **the Feigenbaum constant $\delta$ and reduction parameter $\alpha$ do not seem to be related to other constants** (that is, numerically), even not to each other. In fact I have never seen them expressed as an integral, any kind of series or product, a nested expression, ... The only thing I have found on the internet is [this algorithmic approach](http://marvin.sn.schule.de/~inftreff/modul48/modul48.htm) which further links to [this](http://marvin.sn.schule.de/~inftreff/modul24/task24.htm), but it seems rather like an "a posteriori" method, being interested more in the algorithm than in the nature of $\delta$. Anyway, I would *not* expect the prominent occurrence of the number $163$ in the algorithm to have a deeper meaning.

On the other hand, I wouldn't be *too* surprised to see $\delta$ written as a continued fraction with "defineable" terms, given the fact that it can be defined by 
$\delta=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\mu_n-\mu_{n-1}}{\mu_{n+1}-\mu_n}$, where the $\mu_n$ are the bifurcation points of an iterated map. But I have never seen one either. Any leads?

Comment: I don't think this should have the functional analysis tag, but I admit I can't think of others to suggest

Answer (score 10):

The Feigenbaum constant is the largest eigenvalue of the derivative of the renormalisation operator at its unique fixed point.  There is a beautiful article of Lyubich in the October 2000 Notices of the AMS, entitled "[The Quadratic Family as a Qualitatively Solvable Model of Chaos](http://www.ams.org/notices/200009/fea-lyubich.pdf)", in which he summarises the connection between universality and renormalisation (pages 1046, 1049-1051).

That doesn't directly answer your question, but hopefully that interpretation of the Feigenbaum constant, together with Lyubich's article and/or the references therein, may be of  interest.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the papers by Keith Briggs referenced in the Wikipedia article about the Feigenbaum constants?  They were computational too, but there was math in them.